# Is there a way to make "pseudo-anonymous" possible in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My boss wants to test out a database website project's internal stuff directly, without prompting username and password. I don't think it's possible anonymously even if you set  <'authentication mode="None"> on the web.config file, as the SQL server will just deny anonymous request and I'm not allowed to modify the company's server.

A solution I can think of however, is to have a version with auto-login, with predetermined username and password, then directly go to the main page, to have an illusion of "going anonymous". Is this possible?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you want. You can use any type of SQL authentication, just write it into connection string of your web application. Your ASP.NET users may authenticate in any way you implement it or even enter website anonymously, they do not need to know your SQL credentials.

Comment: Have you tried modifiying your connectionstring?